# Redirecting to many times error in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following protect handler to protect some URLs from users that are not signed in

```
exports.protect = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.cookies.jwt) {
    return res.redirect("/auth");
  }
  const verifiedToken = await verifyJwt(
    req.cookies.jwt,
    process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY
  );

  if (!verifiedToken.id) {
    return res.redirect("/auth");
  }
  const user = await userModel.findOne({ _id: verifiedToken.id });
  if (!user) {
    return res.redirect("/auth");s
  }
  if (user.passwordChangedAt) {
    if (new Date(verifiedToken.iat * 1000) < user.passwordChangedAt) {
      res.clearCookie("jwt");
      return res.redirect("/auth");
    }
  }
  user._id = verifiedToken.id;
  req.user = user;

  next();
};
```

and I use it like this in my route handlers

**my auth route handler:**

```
router.post("/signup", authController.signup);
router.post("/signin", authController.signin);

router.use(authController.protect);

router.post("/password", authController.updatePassword);
```

**my views route handler:**

```
router.get("/auth", viewController.showAuthPage);

router.use(authController.protect);

router.get("/", viewController.showIndexPage);
router.get("/auth/account", viewController.showAccountPage);
```

and I use both route handlers in app.js by this order:

```
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/", viewRoutes);
```

With this, I can't access any route of my page and it just gives me `127.0.0.1` redirected you too many times error.
When I remove protect from my `authRoutes` it just works fine.
when I use `viewRoutes` before auth, it doesn't give me that error but all routes in `authRoute` will be inaccessible and my app doesn't reach any of them.

This is my project in Github and you can check all of it:
[here](https://github.com/far1dghaderi/Chat-app)

Comment: in what routes do you need protection? with `router.use()` it will always fire it

Comment: I need it to apply on all routes that come after it in each file